# How to import a module which opens a file in the same directory as the module?

Tags: python, python-os

I am trying to call a function `is_english_word` in a module `dict.py` in package `dictionary`. Here is the hierarchy:

```
DataCleaning
|___ text_cleaner.py
|___ dictionary
     |___ dict.py
     |___ list_of_english_words.txt
```

To clarify, I have `dict.py` and `list_of_english_words.txt` in one package called `dictionary`.

Here is the import statement written in `text_cleaner.py`:

`import DataCleaning.dictionary.dict as dictionary`

and, here is the code written in `dict.py`:

```
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__')), 'list_of_english_words.txt')) as word_file:
    english_words = set(word.strip().lower() for word in word_file)


def is_english_word(word):
    return word.lower() in english_words
```

But when I run the `text_cleaner.py` file, it shows an import error as it cannot find the `list_of_english_words.txt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Analytics Practice/Social Media Analytics/analyticsPlatform/DataCleaning/text_cleaner.py", line 1, in <module>
    import DataCleaning.dictionary.dict as dictionary
  File "E:\Analytics Practice\Social Media Analytics\analyticsPlatform\DataCleaning\dictionary\dict.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__')), 'list_of_english_words.txt')) as word_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\Analytics Practice\\Social Media Analytics\\analyticsPlatform\\DataCleaning\\list_of_english_words.txt'
```

But when I run the `dict.py` code itself, it shows no error. I can clearly see that the `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))` points to the directory of `text_cleaner.py` and not of `dict.py`. How do I make the import of my module `dict.py` independent of from where it is called?

Comment: Try to change `os.path.realpath('__file__')` to `os.path.realpath(__file__)`.

Comment: Works! Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the string `'__file__'` to `os.path.realpath` instead of the variable `__file__`.

Change:

```
os.path.realpath('__file__')
```

To:

```
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```